# Composition and inheritance in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, composition

So here is the case. I have class A and B. Class A has a member in it which is Class B

```
Public Class A
    public _lstB as list (of B)
    public sub new()
        _lstB = B.Init()
    end sub
end Class

Public Class B
    public shared sub Init() as list (of B)
        ....
    end sub
End Class
```

No what I want to do is create a derived class for A and B (lets say DA and DB). I would like the member B to be replace with DB in  DA. Is this possible?

```
Public Class DA
    inherits A
    public _lstDB as list (of DB)

    public sub new()
        mybase.new 
        _lstDB = DB.Init()
    end sub
end Class

Public Class DB
    inherits B
    public shadows shared sub Init() as list (of DB)
        ....
    end sub
End Class
```

I'm entirely sure this is the way to go, because in the call to

```
mybase.new
```

An entire list (of B) is going to be created in the base class that will never endup being used!

Comment: Your code doesn't show any derivations in DA and DB.

Comment: you could create a base class which has the common properties and methods for A and DA, then both can inherit from that implementing B or DB as needed.  Or make the base generic so you specify B or DB as T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always free to put whatever members you want in base classes and derived classes; there's nothing stopping you from doing that.  How you want to use those classes is up to you.  If you *need* a collection of `B` instances in your `A` class, then that's fine, or if you need a collection of `DB` classes in `DA`, that's fine too.

You could also code it up so that when you're adding an instance of `DB` to the collection you have in the `DA` class, you add that instance to the base class' (`A`) collection which is OK because `DB` derives from `B`.  For instance, if you have this method in `A`:

```
Public Overridable Sub AddNew(item As B)
    _lstB.Add(item)
End Sub
```

and this method in `DA`:

```
Public Overrides Sub AddNew(item As B)
    MyBase.AddNew(item)
End Sub
```

Then you are only ever storing one collection, in the base class `A`.

It all depends on how you want to use your class -- what your specific needs are for your design.

Comment: `and this method in B:` you mean in DA i guess. However may be the OP wants a way to ensure to make sure that in the _lstB of DA all items *have to* be of type DB, so that adding a B-not-DB to DA would no be allowed?